# A PFUser Deleting Their Own Account

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

In my project I will like to allow the user to delete their own account. I have googled around for this answer but nothing comes up. I only get how to delete objects. Currently the only way I know how to do this is to manually delete the user myself in the Parse Dashboard. How do I give the users access in the app to delete themselves (their accounts)?

Comment: This is not recommended to have on client code because the CLP required would let anyone delete anyone else's account.  Add a cloud function like `deleteMyAccount` and delete `request.user` using the master key, so that it requires the request to come from a currently logged in user.  Have the CLP disallow object deletion for your User class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their documentation you can call this:

```
func deleteInBackground(block: PFBooleanResultBlock? = nil)
```

> Deletes the PFObject asynchronously and executes the given callback
>   block.

So you could do something like this:

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
    PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (deleteSuccessful, error) -> Void in
        // User deleted, log out the user
        PFUser.logOut()
    })         
}
```

In the given callback block you logout with `PFUser.logOut()`.

Answer (score 1):

`PFUser` is a subclass if `PFObject`, it's built-in but apart from that it's an ordinary Parse class. So you can delete a user in the same way as you can delete any custom Parse object.